# SASS percentage

Tags: css, sass, percentage

Hello SOF guys and girls :)

Is there is any chance to get the result of this mathematical example, using Sass (I mean the final result in output.css file):

> 1000 - 20% = 800

For example, if I trying something like this:

```
$people: 1000
$dumb_by_trump: percentage(0.2)
$total_adequate: $people - $dumb_by_trump

us poll
    hello_world: $total_adequate
```

Then I'll see in my output.css file the result as:

```
us poll {
hello_world: 980%; }
```

But we need to see "800" as a result. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply percentage by your constant value

```
$people: 1000
$dumb_by_trump: percentage(0.2)
$total_adequate: $people - $people*($dumb_by_trump/100%)

us pool
    hello_world: $total_adequate
```

---

### Result

```
us pool {
  hello_world: 800;
}
```

Comment: Great! But we'll have errors if try add some other parametrs(

Comment: Please clarify what parameters you added and errors you got.

Comment: '$year: 2016' and add to .us pool: 'date: $year', then we get error: > Inconsistent indentation: 4 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab

Comment: Your error message is clear. You use tab for indentation.
Be consistent and use 4 spaces to indenting.

And don't forget to mark answer as accepted if the answer works for you.